# Getting attribute from class using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How would I get the attribute 'src' from the following tag:

```
<div class="entry"><img width="300" height="200" src="http://domain/myimg.jpg" alt="text" /></div>
```

Comment: Multiple ways of getting the src of that element. What have you tried so far? Can you give that element an ID? If so you can access the src by: `document.getElementById('ImageID').src;`

Comment: Do you have access to jquery? If so, just use `$('div.entry img').attr('src')` to get the source attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using an ID for the 'entry' element (or directly on the image element) instead of a class.

If that's not possible use this:

```
var x = document.querySelector('.entry img');
alert('src: ' + x.getAttribute('src'));
```